# Is it secure to use GET variables in a MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, security, http

I have a simple scenario: a user connects to "get.php?city=london", the server then searches the MySQL database for the data matching that request and outputs it.

I am using the following code to do this:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect( 'localhost', 'user', 'pass') or die('Could not connect to mysql server.' );
mysql_select_db('mydb', $con) or die('Could not select database.');

if(!isset($city)) return;
$c=$_GET["city"];

$q = "select * FROM cities WHERE city = '{$c}'";
$re = mysql_query($q);
... etc
```

Is it secure to simply insert the GET variable into the query like this? Will this make me vulnerable to a MySQL injection? Is there a more secure way to do this?

Regards

UPDATE:

would that be more secure?:

```
if(!isset($city)) return;
$city=$_GET["city"];

$q = "SELECT row1, row2 WHERE city= ?;";
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'pass', 'dbname');

$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
if($stmt->prepare($q)){
  $stmt->bind_param("s", mysql_real_escape_string($city));
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->bind_result($row1, $row2);
  while ($stmt->fetch()) {
       //do stuff with the data in the $row array
   }
 $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: Using `mysql_*` extension itself is becoming increasingly in-secure. Use `mysqli`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+injection

Comment: I suggest using prepared statements. These seem to be the most secure these days.

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com. 'nuff said

Comment: @user1908375 remove the first line (the if statement) and the call to `mysql_real_escape_string`. It is unnecessary when using prepared statements. Last thing, the call to `stmt_init` is unnecessary. There is a [prepare](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) method that you should use.

Answer (score 4):

It's not secure at all, GET requests can be faked by simply changing the web address.

Answer (score 4):

Trusting user input is dangerous. Someone could change the value of the city parameter, inject SQL into your query, and gain access to your data. **You should be using prepared statements.** That means that you need to use either the mysqli extension or the [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) extension.

I recommend using the PDO extension, mainly because it allows you to switch databases in the future without having to re-write all the code.

Answer (score 3):

No they are not in mysql_* functions. You need to sensitize them using mysql_real_escape_string.

Better to use PDO with bindParams and the PDO library will do it for you.

php.net/pdo_mysql

https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: Hohoho! I won this time my friend!

Comment: haha its late here in my timezone 1:30 AM and may need to sleep soon :)

Comment: Hahaha 2 PM over here! You should, I guess your loosing fast typing ability as you longer stay awake!

Answer (score 0):

If you use mysql_real_escape_string user couldn't pass a string to mysql injection. On that purpose, for cities, I think there are not problem to use GET. However if you use personal user information I would use $_POST

Comment: It is possible, if the charset is modified, to do sql injections while using `mysql_real_escape_string`, but it is a very very very far edge case.